# how to avoid the image that is converted using changing the extension of notepad file to jpeg

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, security

As we know if we create a simple notepad file and changing the extension  to jpeg
it will convert the text file into jpeg file .There might be chances of some malicious program that
is written in notepad file .
1.I want to check this type of image file how i will do it .
2.Is there any trick so that i can find this type of converted file

using .net c#,asp.net,vb.net

Answer (score 3):

The file extension has no relevance to its content, it's just a matter of pre-processing the first few bits of the file to see what it is. (Then, if you can determine the type from that, you can proceed with that file's parsing agent).

For example:

- Image files can begin with `ÿØÿà[NUL][DLE]JFIF` as their starting bits.
- PDFs can begin with with `%PDF-`
- Compressed files can begin with `PK`, `Rar!` or other variations depending on compression algorithm.

Best thing I can say would be try to run the file through `System.Drawing.Image`. if it's in-fact an image, the parser won't choke on it. If it's not, you'll get some kind of exception and you know it's either not an image, or is and is mal-formed (harmful).

As an aside (because it was kind of bugging me) saying *"As we know if we create a simple notepad file and changing the extension to jpeg it will convert the text file into jpeg file"* isn't entirely true. All you're doing is specifying the default application to open the file up. A text file named to `.jpg`, `.png` or even `.xyz` is still a text file, it's just no longer using notepad (or whatever is your default) to open it.